# Setting TintColor on UIAlertController works for everything but iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uialertcontroller

In my appDelegate, I'm setting:

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Later on, I'm setting the tintColor of an UIAlertController so that the buttons it shows are blue, like so:

```
uiAlertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

On iPhone devices, the buttons are blue as expected.  However, on iPads, the buttons are red.  Why is the tintColor not being overridden only on iPad devices?

Comment: One issue I've encountered that I believe is an iOS bug is that the only way I can successfully modify the tint color of `UIAlertController` is by setting it *after* it is presented. So I make the `present` call first and then set its `tintColor` on the next line. Perhaps this is your issue as well?

Comment: Yeah, I've actually tried setting it after presenting and also in the callback but to no avail :(

Comment: `UIAlertController` is intended to be used as-is according to Apple Docs, so I wouldn't be surprised if setting any property on the view had undefined behavior. Your best bet would be to set `tintColor` of the app's main window, which is where `UIAlertController` gets its `tintColor` from.

Comment: If that doesn't work and you're presenting the alert in a popover on iPad, try playing with the `UIAlertController`'s `popoverPresentationController`.